# Haar measure on $ \mathbb{R} × \mathbb{T}$ and on dual $\mathbb{R} × \mathbb{T}$

Tags: harmonic-analysis

I've solved this exercise somewhat.To complete it please help me

Haar measure on G $=$ translation invariant on G
$$ μ(A)=μ(A+t)$$  if $ G=\mathbb{R}$ then Haar measure on G is lebesgue measure.  and if

$G=\mathbb{T}$ then Haar measure on G is $dt/2π$. I know that $μ_\mathbb{R}× μ_\mathbb{T}$ is a

Haar measure on product group $\mathbb{R} × \mathbb{T}$ .

$$ f : \mathbb{R} × \mathbb{T}→\mathbb{C}\quad by \quadμ(f)=
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{T}} f(x,t) (dt/2π) ~ \mathrm{d}{x}. $$

Let $G=\mathbb{R} × \mathbb{T}\quad,\widehat{\mathbb{G} }=\widehat{\mathbb{R} × \mathbb{T}}=\widehat{\mathbb{R} }×\widehat{ \mathbb{T}}=\mathbb{R} × \mathbb{Z}$

the dual measure on $\widehat{\mathbb{G} }$ is  measure on $\mathbb{R} × \mathbb{Z}$.

$$g : \mathbb{R} × \mathbb{Z}→\mathbb{C}\quad by \quadρ(g)=
\int_{\mathbb{R}} ∑g(x,n)  ~ \mathrm{d}{x}. $$

> if μ and ρ are correct measures?